# How to disable tooltip in google geo chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I need disable tooltip in google geo chart. I tried `tooltip.trigger: 'none'` and other tries, but I can´t disable tooltip.

How to disable tooltip in google geo charts?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a look around and tried a few things but it seems that this particular bit of functionality is not part of Geo charts. With other charts, you can do the following and have tooltips disabled:

```
var options = {
    tooltip {
       trigger: 'none'
    }
};
```

A [workaround I came across is to create a `div` that just sits on top of the map](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/wwz_Fhs8ah0) and that disables the interactivity of the map. Not the best solution but a work around until it's made available. You can see it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/JspTt/).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what browsers your site/app need to support a simple CSS one-liner will disable interactivity.

```
#map {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will cause the map to appear as a static image with no interactivity. But again, it's [not supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Answer (score 0):

[According to asgallant on 12-09-12](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-visualization-api/J-u_JIq_C90):

> You can disable the tooltips by setting the option
>   enableRegionInteractivity: false, which also disables clicking on
>   regions.  The API does not expose a mouseover event for the geo
>   charts, so if you want to do your own, you will have to hook the mouse
>   events on the SVG/VML manually.  As far as I am aware, there is no
>   good way to map an SVG/VML element to a DataTable element, though.

Answer (score 0):

To remove tooltip just add the below options:

```
var options = {
    tooltip: { trigger: 'none'}
}
```

Full code:

```
var map_container = document.getElementById('map_div');
var options = {
    tooltip: { trigger: 'none'}
}
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(map_container);
chart.draw(data, options);`
```